# How to find $ \lim_{n \to \infty}\prod_{i=0}^{n}\frac {qn+ip+1}{qn+ip}$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

How to find

$$L=\lim_{n \to \infty}\prod_{i=0}^{n}\frac {qn+ip+1}{qn+ip}\,,$$

where $p\in\Bbb N ,p \neq \{0,1\},q>0$?

Also, I'm bound to using elemental methods.

Comment: Can you give some context to the question, in what context did it appear?

Comment: @OneAndOnlyDaniel It's not part of a bigger exercise or a specific chapter. The only context that I have is that it's part of calculus, which doesn't help that much.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: Take the $\ln$ on both sides:

$$\ln L=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=0}^n\ln\left(\frac{qn+ip+1}{qn+ip}\right)$$

$$\implies L=\exp\left(\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=0}^n\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{qn+ip}\right)\right)$$

Now, you have reduced the problem to an infinite series.